# Jenkins pipeline pass a value from Shell script to Groovy script

Tags: java, bash, shell, jenkins, groovy

I have a jenkins script which will get the http status code of an url via shell script. I need the value to pass from shell script to groovy one. I tried my below code, but its not working.

It will print the value inside shell script, but outside shell script, its not printing.

```
def code=""
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                script{
                    try{
                        sh '''#!/bin/bash
                        selinium_grid_status=`curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://localhost:4444` ;
                        code=$selinium_grid_status
                        echo $code
                        '''
                        echo code
                    }catch (e){
                         print"no value"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know how we can get the value outside shell script.

Comment: I don't undrestand _outside shell script, its not printing_. The only print outside the shell script happens if an exception occurs, in which case you output _no value_. What else do you expect?

Comment: echo code never returns the value @user1934428

Comment: You have in your script definition the Groovy statement `echo code`, but you never assign anything to the Groovy variable `echo`. BTW, I would use here `println` instead of `echo`. The latter is not a builtin Groovy function, but it works because a definition for it is provided by Jenkins. With `println` you stay within the Groovy standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
script {
  env.code=sh returnStdout: true, script: 'curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://localhost:4444'
}
```

In this case env.code will be accessible in entire pipeline.

Comment: could you please let me know where env.mess_start is used above ?

Comment: sorry, didn't change it. env.mess_start is from my pipeline. it should be env.code